# Dynamically add sections in Hub Control in MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime

I'd like to add dynamically sections in hub in MVVM, I can do it by getting the hub control by a event (like "Loaded") and inject the new sections in but that's mean I break the MVVM by referencing the View in the ViewModel.

So I'm trying to create a list of objects and bind it to the Hub.Sections (which is a IList) using a Convertor to transform them from object to HubSection (and setting the ContentTemplate).

The thing is I can't find a way to bind the Hub.Sections, the attribute to bind a source doesn't seem to be exposed by the Hub control in Xaml.

Should I use a listView instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hub`s are not binding friendly and I have suffered from this before also and had to do it manually. I little bit of research yielded in excellent solution to this : http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2014/01/05/Using-the-Windows-81-Hub-as-an-ItemsControl.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, really helped me ! Just had to modify the DataContext part.